# How to avoid execution of the onchange function of a control in flex when application is loaded for 1st time?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a combo box control in my flex application:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="ispList" width="230" borderColor="#000000"
             change="queryHandlerMaster(event)" color="#000000">
```

I observed that `queryHandlerMaster` is unnecessarily called when application is just loaded.
How to avoid this call?

Comment: I check this example for the Flex SDK 4.5.1. And I don't find that `queryHandlerMaster` is called when an application is just loaded. Could you specify your Flex SDK version.

Comment: Indeed it shouldn't, unless you programatically set the selected item somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possibilities

1. Don't add the listener within the Flex. Add an "addedToStage" listener to the parent component/application and within that handler, add your event with AS3
2. Create a global boolean called "initLoad" and set it to true. When you enter the handler, you check for the initLoad. If true, set it to false. If false, run the handler code. This obviously won't work if there are multiple handlers that need to be stopped

That said, the onChange shouldn't be fired on App init. My guess is you are modifying the ComboBox shortly after app init and because of how fast programs run, you perceive it as happening on app init.